# Autogenerated files getting checked out in TFS

Tags: tfs

The problem that I'm facing is that the autogenerated files are getting checked out which is incorrect. I strongly believe that there will be some way out to avoid that so can somebody please help.

I'm using LLblgenpro ORM which generates the entity classes mapped to a particular schema, however the autogenerated files are not submitted into TFS only the project files that have references are checked in. So other people can take the latest code run the batch file and get the autogenerated files.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you provide some more information?  Do you have a `.gitignore`?  Are these files in the `.gitignore` and are being tracked anyway?  Do the files exist in the repository?

Comment: Hi Edward, The files are generated by the ORM tool. So its like every developer has their own generated entity file, so the generated entity class files are not in the Version control system. It is only the reference that gets submitted in the Version system.

Comment: Could you be more specific on what is getting submitted to TFS every time you check-in?

Comment: I sorted out the problem, actually the projects were not bound to the source control which was causing the files to get checked out.